# Displaying image selected between collection view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, didselectrowatindexpath

I have `structs` as follows in a  `First Collection View Controller`

```
struct Area{
    var name = String()
    var image = String()  
}
var area = [Area]()
```

and in `Second Collection View Controller`

```
struct AreaSelected {
   var imageSelected = String()
}
 var areaSelected = [AreaSelected]()
```

I want to display image selected from `First Collection View Controller` in the `Second Collection View Controller`.

So I did this for navigating them to Second Collection View Controller at `didSelectItemAt indexPath`

```
   let indexPaths = self.areaCV!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
   var indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
   let detailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as? SecondViewController
   detailViewController?.areaSelected = [self.area[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]]
```

Them I am getting following compiler error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Area' to expected element type
>   'AreaSelected'

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically

```
 let selectedArea = self.area[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
 detailViewController?.areaSelected = [AreaSelected(imageSelected: selectedArea.name)]
```

PS: You are using different (incompatible) types in different view controllers so definitely you can't assign it directly to each other.

PSS: Much easier, cleaner and better to setup segue on CellSelected between ViewControllers, and assign `areaSelected` in `func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: Can you please explain why they are incompatible?

Comment: Because they are different data types. You can't assign a property of one data type to a property that takes a different type.

Comment: First is `var area = [Area]()`, while second is `var areaSelected = [AreaSelected]()`

Comment: Thanks for your explantions :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, your first struct is type: `FirstCollectionViewController.Area` and the second has a type `SecondCollectionViewController.AreaSelected`. The two are as different as `Int` and `String`, you can't assign one to another as you can't do `let number: Int = "Of course no"`. However you can define a common type:

```
protocol AreaDescription { 
    var image: String { get }
}

class FirstVC: ... {

    struct Area: AreaDescription {
        var name: String
        var image: String
    }
}

class SecondVC: ... {

    struct AreaSelected: AreaDescription {
        var name: String
        var image: String
    }
}
```

And set your property as:

```
var areaSelected = [AreaDescription]()
```